# What should I do to prevent python from giving a name error for "update" while creating a Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, nameerror

I confronted with this error message while I was trying to get input from the user for my telegram bot. Thanks for your help already.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

bot.polling()

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.8.1-py3.9.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 620, in polling

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.8.1-py3.9.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 679, in __threaded_polling

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.8.1-py3.9.egg\telebot\__init__.py", line 642, in __threaded_polling

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.8.1-py3.9.egg\telebot\util.py", line 130, in raise_exceptions

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytelegrambotapi-3.8.1-py3.9.egg\telebot\util.py", line 82, in run

File "C:\Users\Desktop\CalendarGo\Main.py", line 22, in set
    user_input = update.message.text

NameError: name 'update' is not defined
```

```
import os
import telebot
from telebot.types import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters, CommandHandler, MessageHandler


API_KEY = "API_KEY"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["Set"])
def set(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please enter the word")
    user_input = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text(do_something(user_input))

def do_something(user_input):
    answer = "You have wrote me " + user_input
    return answer
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I assume the error is from the line `user_input = update.message.text`? Where is the `update` variable defined?

Comment: Yes, the error is in that line. I don't know how to define the update variable

Comment: What is the update variable meant to be? did you write all this code yourself or have you copied it from somewhere else?

Comment: Looking at the example https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/ in the section "A simple echo bot", it looks like you maybe just want to operate directly on the message argument, e.g. maybe `user_input = message.text` , `message.reply_text(do_something(user_input))` will work?